# How can I know if the smartphone is located in United States

Tags: android, position, units-of-measurement, country

My Android application tracks the position of the user when he goes for a walking or running, it also shows the distance and the average speed.

The problem I have is that I think that United States still use the mile. So how can I manage if the smartphone is in United States (to use the mile) or in Spain for example (to use the kilometer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use current [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for example, and parse the result. I think it`s much simpler than parse result from location.

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States) 
Locale.getDefault().toString()          ---> en_US
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()---> English
```